# Verify a method is called inside a method without calling other methods inside that method

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, mockito, spring-test

```
public class ServiceClass {
    @Autowired
    ConnClient connClient;
    public void abc() {
         result = connClient.query(arg1, arg2); // verify called once.
         allDocsReturned = result.getResults(); // throws NPE
    }
}
```

I need to verify that **connClient.query(arg1,arg2)** is called at least once. So in the test cases file i am calling the method **abc()**

```
@InjectMocks
ServiceClass serviceClass;
@Mock
ConnClient connClient;
@Test
public void testABC() {
  serviceClass.abc();
  verify(connClient, times(1)).query(arg1,arg2);
}
```

I get NullPointerException because of the line **result.getResults()** called above as result is null, and the test case getting failed. 
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to mock the call to `connClient.query` and `ResultSet`:

```
@InjectMocks
ServiceClass serviceClass;
@Mock
ConnClient connClient;
@Test
public void testABC() {
  ResultSet rs = mock(ResultSet.class);
  when(rs.getResults()).thenReturn(//here return the object of type of your variable allDocsReturned);
  when(connClient.query(arg1,arg2)).thenReturn(rs);
  serviceClass.abc();
  verify(connClient, times(1)).query(arg1,arg2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But the call serviceClass.abc() makes result variable null.

Comment: @Mock                                                                                                                  Result result;                                 
when(connClient.query(arg1, arg2)).thenReturn(result);
when(result.getResults()).thenReturn("xyz");
serviceClass.abc() // GIVES NPE

Comment: Mockito.when works fine and mocks things. But when i call serviceClass.abc() that line generates NPE as result becomes null. The mocked when(connClient.query(arg1,arg2)).thenReturn(result) not acting/injected in serviceClass.abc() call.

Comment: Can you try   when(connClient.query(arg1,arg2)).thenReturn(any(ResultSet.class));

Comment: org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Invalid use of argument matchers!
0 matchers expected, 1 recorded

Comment: What is the type of allDocsReturned variable?

Comment: The type is QueryResponse, so wrote .thenReturn(any(QueryResponse.class));

Comment: From the package org.apache.solr.client.solrj.response?

Comment: Also, please specify the type of result. Sorry, to bother you this much..but it is very interesting :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174716/discussion-between-santanu-and-garima-gupta).

Comment: The error occurs since any() can only be used for matching method parameters but not for specifying the return type

Comment: Try QueryResponse qr=mock(QueryResponse.class);
when(qr.getResults()).thenReturn(new SolrdocumentList());
when(connClient.query(arg1,arg2)).thenReturn(qr);

Answer (score 0):

Your class `ConnClient` is a mock which is why the call `connClient.query(arg1, arg2)` will return null ad thus a NPE is thrown when dereferencing the result.

In this case you can specify the return value of the method call, i.e.

```
doReturn(someObject).when(connClient).query(arg1,arg2);
```

where `someObject` is allowed to be a mock (alternatively, you can return a concrete value).

Once this is done, `result` won't be null anymore and no NPE will be thrown.

Note that if `result` is dereferenced later, you also have to mock the `getResults()` call.

Edit:

```
@InjectMocks
ServiceClass serviceClass;
@Mock
ConnClient connClient;
@Mock
Result result;
@Test
public void testABC() {
    doReturn(result).when(connClient).query(arg1,arg2);       
    serviceClass.abc();
    verify(connClient, times(1)).query(arg1,arg2);
}
```

Now result will not be null, however, allDocsReturned will still be null, but will not lead to a NPE with the code posted by you

Comment: I tried this. result is still null. Can you post a small example?

Comment: doReturn(result).when(connClient).query(arg1,arg2); This result is not acting/injected in serviceClass.abc() call and i am getting NPE.

Comment: please provide a headers of your TestClass. For fully understanding how you are initialize and run you test. Usually it is some kind of `@RunWith`..